# How can I set the value and the datatype when creating a new SqlParameter?

Tags: sql-server

I have my code setting up a parameter for QuestionsCount and then for Questions:

```
    parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionsCount", chunkSize));

    var p = new SqlParameter("@Questions", questions);
    p.TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList";
    parameterList.Add(p);
```

Is there a way that I can combine the last three lines and create a new SqlParameter with the typeName. I was looking at the definitions but cannot find one that takes the value `(questions)` and the TypeName `"dbo.QuestionList"`.

Comment: I find that table valued parameters require (relatively) verbose setup before you can use them, so I just wrote an extension method: `AddWithValue<T>(this SqlParameterCollection that, string parameterName, string typeName, IEnumerable<T> rows)` that handles setting the type etc. plus empty `IEnumerable<T>`s get passed down as `null` (why that's a requirement I have no idea...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is with an initializer to supply property values not available in the constructor overloads:

```
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter( "@Questions", SqlDbType.Structured ) { TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList", Value = questions });
```

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few overloads for the constructor for SqlParameter, some of which allow you to specify a datatype and optionally a length:

```
var p = new SqlParameter("@Questions", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
p.Value = ":.......";
parameterList.Add(p);
```

Check out the [MSDN documentation on SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.